# If $p$ and $q$ are positive real numbers, show that $\sum_{k=2}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{(lnk)^p}{k^q}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $p$ and $q$ are positive real numbers, show that $$\sum_{k=2}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{(ln k)^p}{k^q}$$
converges

Comment: This series is nothing else than the *p*-th derivative of the [Dirichlet $\eta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) of argument *q*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as you can show that the sequence $$(\ln(k))^p/k^q$$ is decreasing for sufficiently large $k$ you win by the alternating series test.

Write $$f(x) = \frac{\ln(x)^p}{x^q}$$ then we find that $$f'(x) = \frac{px^{-1} \ln(x)^{p-1} - qx^{q-1}\ln(x)^p}{x^{2q}}$$

It is sufficient to show that the numerator is negative for large $x$. That is $$px^{-1} \ln(x)^{p-1} - qx^{q-1}\ln(x)^p < 0$$

For $x>1$ this is equivalent to: $$p - q x^{q} \ln(x) < 0$$

Which certainly holds for large enough $x$. Thus for large enough $k$, the sequence in the series is decreasing, and the series converges.